# What is Swiftly on mac?

Tags: macos

I upgraded to Mavericks a few days ago and since then I keep getting a pop up floating search box randomly. I do not know what triggered it and I do not know where it is from. It is driving me crazy. Can anyone tell me?

I have Alfred and ShiftIt installed.

[image: Just enjoy Swiftly :)]

Comment: As for the trigger, it's pressing Command key (⌘) twice.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Do you have QQ Instant Messenger installed? 
On my computer, this was the cause for this strange popup window.

Comment: YES it is!!!!!!!!

Comment: Drove me crazy !

Answer (score 3):

To close the function, open QQ's Preferences (Shortcut: Cmd + ,) Go to the tab Swifly, then set the launch key to Empty.